# DataTable binding to DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

**XAML file:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="ItemsDataGrid" Margin="0,30,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sl. No." MinWidth="125" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Quantity" MinWidth="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remaining" MinWidth="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost/Each" MinWidth="200" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**XAML.CS File:**

```
private void Page_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _itemsViewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    this.DataContext = _itemsViewModel;
}
```

**ViewModel.cs file:**

```
private DataTable _itemsList;
private List<ItemsModel> ItemsModel;

public DataTable ItemsList
{
    get { return _itemsList; }
    set
    {
        _itemsList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemsList");
    }
}

private List<ItemsModel> _items;

public List<ItemsModel> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

public ItemsViewModel()
{
    LoadItems();
}

private void LoadItems()
{
    CFunctions cFunctions = new CFunctions();
    ItemsList = cFunctions.GetItems();
    ItemsModel = new List<ItemsModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemsList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ItemsModel.Add(new ItemsModel()
        {
            SlNo = int.Parse(ItemsList.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()),
            ItemName = ItemsList.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
            Quantity = int.Parse(ItemsList.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString()),
            Remaining = int.Parse(ItemsList.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString()),
            Cost = int.Parse(ItemsList.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString())
        });

    }
    Items = ItemsModel;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Model.cs file:**

```
class ItemsModel
{
    public int SlNo        { get; set; }
    public int Quantity    { get; set; }
    public int Cost        { get; set; }
    public int Remaining   { get; set; }
    public String ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

If `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` it creates columns and adds the data to those created columns like:

[image]

When it is false the DataGrid is Empty.

Is it the correct way i am doing? Why does it not bind to the columns already created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the:

```
Binding="{Binding Description}"
```

Attributes on each column definition.  You have to explicitly link them to your model class properties.

Answer (score 1):

like Digitlafront says, you need to set the binding

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="ItemsDataGrid" Margin="0,30,0,0"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SlNo, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Sl. No." MinWidth="125" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemName}" Header="Name" MinWidth="200" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity} Header="Total Quantity" MinWidth="200" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Remaining} Header="Remaining" MinWidth="200" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost} Header="Cost/Each" MinWidth="200" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

you also should set the Mode=TwoWay or OneWay as you need it. 
Instead of a List i would use ObservableCollection.